# Parsing Through ListNodes in List

Tags: java

I'm having trouble figuring out why my code won't parse through the `ListNode`s in the `List`s, in order to add a new `String` as a `ListNode`. I'm trying to write the function `add(String s)`, to add a new `ListNode` to the `List`. If the list is empty, I just add the `String` as a `ListNode`, and if not, I parse through using `node` and `myNext`, and then if `node.myNext` is null, I replace it with the newly created `ListNode`. What is the reason this isn't working? It either does not throw an output or it says it is out of bounds.

```
public class List {
    private ListNode myHead;
    private int mySize;

    public List() {
        this.myHead = null;
        this.mySize = 0;
  }

public class ListNode {
    public String myData;
    public ListNode myNext;

    public ListNode(String element, ListNode next) {
        this.myData = element;
        this.myNext = next;
    }


    public ListNode(String element) {
        this(element, null);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.length() == 0;
   }

    public void add(String s) {
        if(this.isEmpty() == true) {
            this.addToFront(s);
        }
        else {
            this.mySize++;
            for(ListNode node = this.myHead; node.myData != null; node = node.myNext) {
                if(node.myNext == null) {
                    ListNode lno = new ListNode(s, null);
                    node.myNext = lno;
                }
                else {
                    node.myData = node.myData;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `node.myData = node.myData;`?

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm not sure what else to put there - it's like a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

In you `ListNode` you can't access methods and variables of your `List` class.
Assuming that you want to add the new `String` at the top of your `List` you should do something like this:

```
public class List {
    private ListNode myHead;
    private int mySize;

    public List() {
        this.myHead = null;
        this.mySize = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.mySize == 0;
    }

    public void add(String s) {
        this.myHead = new ListNode(s, myHead);//add new String as head element
        this.mySize++;
    }
}

public class ListNode {
    public String myData;
    public ListNode myNext;

    public ListNode(String element, ListNode next) {
        this.myData = element;
        this.myNext = next;
    }

    public ListNode(String element) {
        this(element, null);
    }
}
```

If you want to add it at the end of your `List` you can try it like this:

```
public void add(String s) {
        if(this.isEmpty()){
            this.myHead = new ListNode(s, myHead);//add new String as head element
        }else{
            ListNode node = this.myHead;
            while (node.myNext != null){
                node = node.myNext;
            }
            //now you hav the last node of your list
            node.myNext = new ListNode(s,null);
        }
        this.mySize++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have pasted is not complete.

Also, If I am correct, your List is having the ListNodes and thus, it is your List where you should put methods to check if it is Empty (does not have any ListNodes in it) or add, delete, count, search etc. functions.

For isEmpty(), There is no length() defined, so simply check the size to be == 0.
For add(), if it is empty just point myHead to your new ListNode; If you have to add in end, iterate the myHead using a currentNode reference, till its next is null and add.

If it is to be in middle somewhere, you will need to check for ListNode myData to decide where it fits white moving from myHead towards null and once you find a place to insert, you will need to change the [PrevNode] -> new ListNode -> [nextNode]